# Javascript for loop behaviour in arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm currently learning JS and doing some problems on Codewars. I've written a function to solve a problem, but I don't understand why the for loop in JS behaves the way it does in my solution, I'd be glad if anyone could help me. 
The problem is as follows:

Write an algorithm that takes an array and moves all of the zeros to the end, preserving the order of the other elements.

```
moveZeros([1, 2, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 3, 0, 1]) // returns[1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

My solution is:

```
var moveZeros = function(arr) {
    let newarr = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i] === 0) {
            newarr.push(arr[i])
        } else {
            newarr.unshift(arr[i])
        };
    }
    return newarr;
}
```

What my function returns is:

```
[1, 3, 1, 1, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Why does JS put 3 before 2, although its index in the array is 7?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Unshift adds elements to the **beginning** of an array (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift). You should use `push` instead (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is because unshift always adds the number to the beginning of `newarr`

E.g from above code the newarr will look as below:
    `i=0: newarr = [1]
    i=1: newarr = [2,1]
    i=2: newarr = [2,1,0]
    i=3: newarr = [1,2,1,0]
    i=4: newarr = [1,2,1,0,0]
    i=5: newarr = [1,2,1,0,0,0]
    i=6: newarr = [1,1,2,1,0,0,0]
    i=7: newarr = [3,1,1,2,1,0,0,0]
    i=8: newarr = [3,1,1,2,1,0,0,0,0]
    i=9: newarr = [1,3,1,1,2,1,0,0,0,0]`

Answer (score 4):

**Well [`unshift()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift) pushes the value in front of array.**

Have a look at this example.ti understand how `unshift()` works.

```js
let a = [];
 a.unshift(1);
 a.unshift(2);
 a.unshift(3);
 a.unshift(4);
console.log(a);
```

**[`Push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) add values at the back of array.**

look at example below to understand how push works.

```js
let a = [];
     a.push(1);
     a.push(2);
     a.push(3);
     a.push(4);
console.log(a);
```

```js
var moveZeros = function (arr) {
let newarr = [];
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
if (arr[i] === 0) {newarr.push(arr[i])}
else {newarr.unshift(arr[i])};
} return newarr;
}



let op = moveZeros([1, 3, 1, 1, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]);
console.log(op);
```

Comment: "Well unshift() pushes the value in front of array. Push add values at the back of array."

That's right, but for the input [1, 2, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 3, 0, 1] my function returns [1, 3, 1, 1, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0] and NOT [1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]. It switches [2] at index 1 for [3] which in the input is at index 7 and I don't see why

Comment: @Konstantin It reverses everything that isn't zero, try it with another input.

Comment: Your function is return is that way only. as @HMR said except zero it will reverse everything.

Answer (score 2):

using your sample code. You can introduce a *temporary array* to store all zeros that exist. Then concatenate it with the *newarr*

```
var moveZeros = function(arr) {
  let newarr = []; 
  let temp = []; //store all zeros here
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i] === 0) {
      temp.push(arr[i])
  } else {
      newarr.push(arr[i])
  };
 }

 return newarr.concat(temp); //this moves all zeros after the array order
}
```

Also if you want to maintain the function argument i.e the *arr* as the result variable, you can remove all zeros from it after storing each in the *temporaray array*. Then concatenate the *arr* with the *temp*

```
var moveZeros = function(arr) {
  let temp = []; //store all zeros here
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i] === 0) {
      temp.push(arr[i]);
      arr.splice(i,1); /*delete all zeros after storing them this does not affect array order*/
    } 
  }

  return arr.concat(temp);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

welcome to Stack Overflow. The following code will put all zero's at the end of the array and keep the rest in the order they were found:

```js
const moveToEnd = (arr) => {
  const [head, tail] = arr.reduce(
    ([head, tail], val) =>
      val === 0
        ? [head, tail.concat(val)]
        : [head.concat(val), tail],
    [[], []],
  );
  return head.concat(tail);
};
console.log(moveToEnd([1, 2, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 3, 0, 1]));
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use sort() function for array ordering:

```
var sortedArray = [1, 2, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 3, 0, 1].sort(function(a,b){
 return b === 0 && (b - a) 
});
```

the b - a indicates that order descendant.

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_array_sort.asp

Comment: ..."preserving the order of the other elements"?